# In Hierarchical edge bundling how to use json string instead of a json file?

Tags: d3.js

Initially i tried it with json file in basic html. It seems to work fine but when i tried to change the json file to json string, I'm unable to get the data from the json string.
please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your data is stored in a variable already, you don't need the additional `d3.json` call. That is, instead of something like

```
d3.json("http://...", function(error, data) {
});
```

you would use the variable that contains your JSON directly.

Comment: `var classes = JSON.parse(obj);`
    `//d3.json("flare-imports.json", function(classes) { `
   ` var nodes = cluster.nodes(packages.root(classes)),`
    `links = packages.imports(nodes),`
   ` splines = bundle(links);`

Comment: I'm using the above code and i commented the second line but still the  classes is not getting

Comment: I would guess that your JSON is different from `flare-imports.json` then.

Comment: Hi Lars It is working now...... I just missed one square bracket in json string     Thanks for helping